# Copy changed files in Jenkins

Tags: file, copy, jenkins

I'm using Jenkins for building my projects. I'm using Ant to do the compilation itself.
When build finishes I'd like to copy files that were compiled in this build to some directory. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could do this as part of your Ant project using the [Ant copy](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html) task.  Best practice is to clean the directory containing your compiled binaries at the start of each build, so you should just be able to copy the whole directory without filtering the contents.

Comment: After reading the docs for Ant copy task I cannot see how this can be done. what I need is to copy ONLY those files that were changed/compiled in this build.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to specifically find changed files, you could take a recursive md5 over your Target directory before and after your build, and only copy those files which do not match the prebuild checksum.

This being said, if you've got a clean build directory you should just copy everything over; changed files will get copied as needed, and unchanged files will copy but won't impact the application.

Comment: But can this be done with what Ant provides out-of-the-box or maybe someone has done that and I can use his work?